# DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tenho um *script* de consulta simples PHP+MySQL:

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td ><h2>GERENCIAR  ANUNCIOS </h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >

<table >
  <tr>
    <th >ID</th>
    <th >Nome</th>
    <th >Email</th>
    <th >Ação</th>

</tr>
<?php

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

// Executa uma consulta
$sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` , `user_email` FROM `users`";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id        = $dados["user_id"];
    $nome      = $dados["user_name"];
    $email = $dados["user_email"];

    echo "<tr>
    <td > $id </td>
    <td > $nome </td>
    <td > $email </td>
    <td > <a href='excluir.php?user_id=$id'>excluir </a></td>
    </tr>\n";
    }

echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows . '<br><br>';

?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

E um *script* `excluir.php`

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login'); 
    $id = 'user_id';

    $strSQL = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $id";
    mysqli_query($strSQL);

    // Fechar conexão com Banco de Dados
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: index.php");
    ?>
```

Não consigo excluir registros do banco de dados.
O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Provavelmente a solução vai ser o que o @Luis respondeu, mas você deve passar o id por `POST` e tratar os dados que entram no `SQL`

Comment: Tenha em atenção que ao passar o `$id` pelo link poderá ter problemas com *SQLInjection* se não tratar disso na *query* de `DELETE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No excluir.php além do já foi falado, faltou chamar o método corretamente,
mude:

```
mysqli_query($strSQL);
```

para

```
$mysqli->query($strSQL);
```

O mysqli pode ser usado no modo orientado a objetos ou procedural, evite misturar os estilos, no modelo procedural é obrigatório passar a conexão como primeiro argumento nas funções, ve o exemplo do [query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Para evitar o [sql injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91) como foi comentando pode alterar seu código para essa forma:

```
$id = $_GET['user_id'];

$strSQL = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); //prepara e transforma a string em uma consulta
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id); //informa que será enviado um integer ao banco
if($stmt->execute() === false){ // efetua a operação
   echo $stmt->error;
}
```

Enquanto estiver fazendo testes no código comenta as linhas de redirecionamento assim é possível visualizar os erros.

[bind_param - manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[prepare - manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: e ou tambem pode fazer uma condição no começo `if(!is_numeric($_GET['id'])){ header("Location: index.php"); exit;}`

Comment: Alterei e executei. Retornou o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in C:\wamp\www\login\admin\excluir.php on line 7

Comment: @Renan, alterei a resposta.

Comment: @rray, resolvido!

Answer (score 8):

Você está tentando excluir um registro que contenha o valor 'user_id'.
Altere sua linha 2 do `excluir.php` para: `$id = $_GET['user_id'];`

Comment: Eu não programo em php, mas não é correto mandar o ID por GET quando se é uma exclusão de dados.

Comment: Linha 2 do excluir.php alterada e ainda não foi excluído

Comment: @Rod por que não é correto?

Comment: Assim daria pra excluir registros somente mudando o link. Já que o envio é por GET. Não seria isso?

Comment: @gmsantos o  Gustavo, respondeu acima, mas é como eu falei, eu não programo em php

Comment: @Rod o parâmetro ser enviado por POST ou GET não muda nada, pois é possível forjar uma requisição POST. Ao meu ver o correto mesmo seria adotar REST e enviar uma requisição DELETE. Alias, em aplicações RESTFull o id para remover um recurso é passado pela URL.

Comment: claro que o POST também pode ser forjado, porém, deve ter conhecimento, já o GET, é simples URL, se até por engano o usuário digitar, haverá a exclusão, sobre o RESTFull, não conheço php para falar algo...

Answer (score 3):

O problema está no select, você não está selecionando registros do banco de dados, está apenas retornando os valores user_id, user_name , user_email, experimente tirar as aspas simples do Select deixando assim:

```
 // Executa uma consulta
 $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name , user_email FROM users";
```

Comment: Deu certo, era isso. Só estou agora resolvendo a questão do sql injection.